# Is casting an IEnumerable to an ArrayList O(N) or O(1)?

Tags: c#, performance, casting, arraylist

When I do this cast:

```
private IEnumerable objects;
ArrayList castedObjects = (ArrayList)objects;
```

Is this a "direct" cast, or the enumerable is converted into an ArrayList via an internal method (that presumably loops through all the elements)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is either a "direct" cast (if the underlying object is actually an instance of `ArrayList`), or you'll get an [exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx). No implicit creating of an `ArrayList` object is done "behind the scene".

Answer (score 3):

This is a direct cast. It will only work if the object is an `ArrayList` already, for example:

```
IEnumerable objects = new ArrayList();
ArrayList castedObjects = (ArrayList)objects;
```

If the object is not an `ArrayList` but some other object that implements `IEnumerable`, the cast will fail.

You can create an `ArrayList` from an `ICollection`, for example:

```
ICollection objects = new string[] { "a", "b" };
ArrayList castedObjects = new ArrayList(objects);
```

This will loop through the collection and copy the items to the `ArrayList`, so it's an O(n) operation.

---

Generally you should not use the `ArrayList` class at all, but the generic `List<T>` class that offers strict typing.

Comment: As for using the List<T> you're right, but I'm using a third party library that makes heavy use of ArrayLists and I am forced to cast here and there.

Comment: Is there no alternative to this third-party library? Using .NET 1.1 approaches in a modern app is just going to cause you pain.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `objects` actually is. It is referenced as an `IEnumerable`, but its actual type may be anything that implements `IEnumerable`.

If the reference can be cast to an `ArrayList` (because it already is, or inherits from, `ArrayList`) then it is O(1). If it cannot, then you'll just get an exception.